# Pausing and resuming a runnable thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have an activity (not my main activity) that plays some sounds and draw some graphics in a runnable thread. There is an imagebutton with which I'm supposed to suspend and resume the thread. But whatever I try the thread just runs on. I'm totally stuck! Please help.

```
public class PlayInterval extends Activity {
   private Handler customHandler;
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_playinterval);
      final ImageButton playPauseButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playPauseButton);//Play/Pause
      playPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
           onPlayPauseClicked(playPauseButton,(String)playPauseButton.getTag());
        }
     });
     customHandler = new Handler();
     new Thread(new Task()).start();
  }
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
     customHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
     finish();
  }
  class Task implements Runnable {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        // Do really cool stuff
        // and even cooler stuff
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
     }
  }
  private void onPlayPauseClicked(ImageButton playPauseButton, String status) {
     if (status == "playing") {
        playPauseButton.setTag("paused");
        customHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); //TODO suspend here not working!
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
           playPauseButton.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("pause_image", "drawable", getPackageName()));
        } else {
            playPauseButton.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("pause_image", "drawable", getPackageName())));
        }
    } else {
        playPauseButton.setTag("playing");
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 100); //TODO resume here not working!
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            playPauseButton.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("play_image", "drawable", getPackageName()));
        } else {
            playPauseButton.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("play_image", "drawable", getPackageName())));
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you might have to create your own Thread to get that amount of control. Using Thread.sleep() etc..

Comment: Nah, I'm pretty sure it's possible to do it this way. The only thing that needs to change is the: 
     customHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); //TODO suspend here not working!
     customHandler.postDelayed(this, 100); //TODO resume here not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never did get an answer so after trial and error I came up with this. I've red quite alot here on StackOverflow and what I understand this is **NOT** the way it is supposed to be done. But it is working very well, so if anyone could explain why one shouldn't use syncronized methods like this and provide a better answer I would be thankful.
Cheers

```
public class PlayInterval extends Activity {
   private Handler customHandler;
   Boolean isRunning;
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_playinterval);
      final ImageButton playPauseButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.playPauseButton);//Play/Pause
      playPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            onPlayPauseClicked(playPauseButton);
         }
      });
      customHandler = new Handler();
      isRunning=true;
      new Thread(new Task()).start();
   }

   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
      customHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
      finish();
   }

   class Task implements Runnable {
      @Override
      public void run() {
      if (isRunning == true){
         // Do really cool stuff
         // and even cooler stuff
      } else {
         // it is paused
      }
      customHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
   }


   private syncronized void onPlayPauseClicked(ImageButton playPauseButton) {
     if (isRunning==true) {
        isRunning=false;
        playPauseButton.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("play_image", "drawable", getPackageName()));
     } else {
        isRunning=true;
        playPauseButton.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("pause_image", "drawable", getPackageName()));
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: After looking everywhere, this helped me so much. Simple and easy. Thank you :)